# Undefined offset in Abstract.php / Continue to checkout button doesn't work

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, php-5.4

I have upgraded to Magento 1.9.2 and am using the rwd theme (with a few tweaks). I have checkout as guest enabled. When you get to the stage in ordering where you choose between 'Checkout as Guest' or 'Register and Checkout', no matter which option you choose the continue button does not work. I enabled logging and the following errors were in the log although they don't seem to be created by clicking the continue button as such, i.e. clicking the button repeatedly does not create any more errors. Could they nonetheless be the reason the button isn't working?:

```
 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php on line 814
```

and

```
 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/local/Bintime/Sinchimport/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php on line 146
```

The code around line 814 in Abstract.php is:

```
 public function fetchPairs($sql, $bind = array())
 {
      $stmt = $this->query($sql, $bind);
      $data = array();
      while ($row = $stmt->fetch(Zend_Db::FETCH_NUM)) {
            $data[$row[0]] = $row[1];   //This is line 814
      }
      return $data;
 }
```

The code around line 146 in Price.php is

```
 protected function _getItemsData()
 {
      $import=Mage::getModel('sinchimport/sinch');
      $price_breaks=$import->price_breaks_filter;

      if(strstr($price_breaks, ';')){
          $price_ranges = explode(';', $price_breaks);

          foreach ($price_ranges as $price_range) {
                $price_range_value=trim($price_range);
                if($price_range && $price_range!=''){

                     $price_range = explode('-', $price_range);
                     list($minPrice, $maxPrice) = $price_range;  // This is line 146
                     if(((int)$minPrice || $minPrice==0) && ((int)$maxPrice || $maxPrice=='*')){
                          $count=$this->_getResource()->getCountMinMaxPrice($this, $minPrice, $maxPrice);
                          if($count){
                              $data[] = array(
                                      'label' => $this->_renderItemLabelMinMaxPrice($minPrice, $maxPrice),
                                      'value' =>$price_range_value,
                                      'count' => $count,
                                       );
                           }
                      }
                }
           }
           if($data){
               return $data;
           }
       }

       $range         = $this->getPriceRange();
       $dbRanges      = $this->getRangeItemCounts($range);
       $data          = array();

       foreach ($dbRanges as $index=>$count) {
           $data[] = array(
                   'label' => $this->_renderItemLabel($range, $index),
                   'value' => $index . ',' . $range,
                   'count' => $count,
                   );
        }

        return $data;
  }
```

Comment: Notice errors should be turned off on a production store. Do you have Developer Mode turned on in your `index.php`?

Comment: Not yet, but I am about to as per answer below. This is a dev site btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn on SQL Logging.

Example in Lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:

```
protected $_debug               = true;
protected $_logAllQueries       = true;
protected $_logCallStack        = true;
```

Then turn on errors/reporting and put Magento in developers mode, so it will raise a exception and stop executing in `index.php`.

```
$_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'] = true;
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Flush Cache 'full' (just to be on the safe side) and reload page.

Then open your log file in `/var/log/` and scroll down to the last `SELECT ...` query and look at it. Than try this out on your database, and look if its a warning or it has two field pairs. 
Like KEY + VALUE >== `$data[$row[0]] = $row[1];`

Good luck and happy hacking !

Comment: Thanks for answering @Roger. I edited `Mysql.php` as you suggest, then added `$_SERVER` etc before `if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) { Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true); }` and uncommented `ini_set` etc in `index.php`. Then I added an item to my basket and on continue to checkout nothing happened, as before. When I check `system.log` in [magento directory]/var/log there are no more error messages. I also tried 'mysqld.log' in /var/log but nothing. Is there somewhere else I should look?

Comment: What do you mean with: "I also tried 'mysqld.log' in /var/log but nothing." is it empty ? There should be SQL in it... You want to know the last select statement executed.

Comment: I mean that there is only the startup/shutdown info, there are no SQL queries.

Comment: Ok copy that, try this for 'sanity check': assert(get_class(Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read')) == 'Magento_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql'); If it failes 'revert' the adaptor file and find the 'used' adapter...(get_class = dir+filename)

Comment: Sorry ! It's: LIB/MAGENTO/..... not LIB/VARIEN/..... for my instance. (Magento 1.9.2 with my config...), so just do: die(get_class(Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read')‌​)); and read the class name and lookup the file. Sorry, i'm assuming that it would be the same i use for a project. I'm now on a 'fresh' installation....(Oeps, that was silly of me)

Comment: Sorry @Roger, perhaps I've given the impression I know more about Magento than I, in fact, do. In what file am I putting the `die(get_class....`

Comment: Can you also try this: var_dump(Mage::getModel('sinchimport/sinch')->price_breaks_filter); and than you must have a string with price ranges glued with `;` and then ranges with ALWAYS a `-` on every priced range. Because of line, 145:  `$price_range = explode('-', $price_range);` (There isn't a check on array must have atleast 2 elements because of the `list($a, $b) =` on line 146)

Comment: No problem mail me at: lucifer.iix@g{oogle}mail.com i will give you some code for testing. It will call Mage:init and not Mage:run... so you can initialise Mage and then run simple test scripts.

Comment: After quite a bit of guidance from Roger, I discovered that, because I had copied the old Page.xml to my theme before the upgrade and the location of the `jquery-1.10.2.min.js` has changed, none of the jquery on my site was working, let alone the continue to checkout button. I replaced this with the new Page.xml and the button works now. The Undefined Offset errors were not related and point instead to a problem with the Stock in the Channel module, which is a whole different story. Many thanks, Roger.